# How to verify that an http request is not made at all?

Tags: angularjs

how to verify that none of http request method are invoked to do any request. I have this code :

```
 $scope.getSubnetsPageDetails = function (pageNumber) {
        $http.get(URLS.subnetsPagesCount(pageNumber)).success(function (response) {
            $scope.pageDetails = response;
        }).error(function (response, errorCode) {

            });
    };
```

and this test :

```
it("should not allow request with negative page number", function () {

        scope.getSubnetsPageDetails(-1);
        //verify that htt.get is not invoked at all

    });
```

How to verify that http.get is not invoked ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can test that no calls are made by using the `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` method from the [$httpBackend mock](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend).

Usually those kind of verification is done in the `afterEach` section of a Jasmine's tests. On top of this it is common to call another method, `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` to verify that all the expected calls were actually invoked.

Here is the code, where you need to inject the `$httpBackend` mock:

```
var $httpBackend;
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
}));
```

then do you test and at the end:

```
afterEach(function() {
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Of course you could invoke the `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` inside an individual test. The mentioned http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend page has a wealth of information on the topic.